# How to replace string present on next line

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, regexp-replace

I want to replace the string Test string with "Hello
World". I want Hello to be present on first line and World should be present on second line as present in the Main string below

```
" This is a Test
string. This is a Test2 string"
```

The output should be like

```
" This is a Hello
World. This is a Test2 string"
```

Also it should be case insensitive while **replacing**

Please suggest a solution in Oracle SQL.

I tried this query. It is for replacing if "Test string" present on the same line. And it satisfy case insensitive

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('This is a Test string. This is a Test2 string',
                    'Test string',
                    'Hello World',
                   1,
                   0,
                   'i')  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: But the input and output literals are not compatible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex below to get your desired result.

The expression `Test(\W*)string` will match **test**, then any non word characters (in this case spaces and new lines), then the word **string**. It does not match **Test2 string** because the 2 is a word character. The parenthesis are necessary for the next parameter.

`Hello\1World` will place **Hello World** in place of **test string** but putting the \1 between hello and world will retain any characters that were between the **test** and **string** when the expression was matched.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('This is a Test 
 string. This is a Test2 string',
                       'Test(\W*)string',
                       'Hello\1World',
                       1,
                       0,
                       'i') as result
  FROM DUAL;


                                            RESULT
__________________________________________________
This is a Hello
 World. This is a Test2 string
```